# What is the proper way to deal with help vampires that repost closed questions letter for letter under a different account?

Tags: discussion, help-vampire

[image: Self admitted exact copy of]<sub>[now deleted as well as the account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700555/how-to-parse-a-c-array-in-a-c-file-using-a-python-script)</sub>

This is a self admitted copy of *[How to parse a C array in a .c file using a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697604/how-to-parse-a-c-array-in-a-c-file-using-a-python-script)* <sup>now deleted as well</sup> that was posted under a completely separate account/user name.

Notice that the only difference in the title is the trailing `]` that they lazily added when the system would not let them use the exact same title.
<sub>I discovered this behavior when I tried to fix the title and take the trailing `]` out assuming it was a fat finger typo.</sub>

To make matters worse it is a duplicate of a legitimate [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143076/python-cycling-scanning-though-fields-in-an-object) from almost a year ago that has answers.

How many more accounts does this same person have and how many times do they do this a day? Is there something in place that automatically detects exactly the same content (or pretty close which should be easy to do) and auto flags it for moderators or something?

#### What is the most effect and efficient way for the the community to deal with this type of behavior?

Comment: i mean.... we don't have the tools to deal with it, so custom flag would seem to be the obvious answer.

Comment: Ideally you'd want to have automatic mod flags for questions with a sufficiently significant overlap with another question (particularly if the other question is deleted).  Just prohibiting the question only makes them make meaningless changes, as shown here.  A silent mod flag will let the mod merge the accounts, close the question, perhaps delete it (if merited) and so on.

Comment: Let me mention here that Jarrod did try to get this resolved in SOCVR but we have a strict policy on not allowing multiple requests for the same user or for flags.  Due to that rule SOCVR isn't an effective route to handle these cases as we pro-actively move  requests out of our transcript that are in breach with our room rules

Answer (score 22):

A word-for-word repost of a question by two different accounts is almost always worth a custom moderator flag. Make sure you call out that this is an exact copy of another question, so that we don't misread this as someone asking for a question to be closed as a duplicate. A link to the other question is really appreciated, too, since that makes it easy for us to pull them up side-by-side.

Exact duplicate reposts like this are usually the result of one of three things: someone attempting to work around a question ban with new accounts, a group of students or coworkers trying to increase exposure for the same problem, or someone trying to farm reputation by copying a highly-voted old question (usually also then posting plagiarized answers from that question).

While it may seem to be a simple duplicate, these copied questions by multiple users are often threads that have let me unravel voting rings, block question-ban evaders, or track down plagiarists. For example, in this case I was able to remove several question-ban evading accounts as a result of your flag and block a series of IP addresses. Not only will that clean up and remove these questions, it will most likely prevent dozens of other bad questions from being posted by this same person or group.

I should say that it's not a particularly common thing, and I've heard that it would be expensive to query for duplicated questions outside of those asked by one user, so I don't know if it makes sense to have SE work on an automated flag for this. Maybe there's a better way to detect these as they come in, but I don't know what that would be or if it would be worth the development effort and potential computational resources.

Comment: `a group of students or coworkers trying to increase exposure for the same problem` or just an individual doing that.  I see this a lot where someone posts a question, it doesn't get an answer, so they re-post it a bit later to get it back on the front page.  I also see a lot of people re-posting a question when the first is closed/downvoted, just so that people will see a question that doesn't have downvotes on it and not realize it's a bad question.

Comment: I think it just has to do with not understanding what [on hold] means. There's a meta meta post somewhere about that, but I'm too lazy to find it right now.

Comment: if you look they admit they reposted it because it was put on hold and did not received an answer, so this is not some kind of crowd sourcing, it is the same person with to different accounts/identities.

Comment: @BradLarson does this apply only to question posted by multiple accounts? What should be done on case of the same account reposting the exact same OT question after it was closed? I cannot mark as duplicate since the other one didn't get answered, obviously. Sure we could just close vote but shouldn't this behavior be discouraged in some stronger way? I researched on meta first and according to the comments here decided to flag for mod attention but it was declined saying I should use a standard flag... But which? Can you elaborate? Thank you. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124421/)

Answer (score 11):

Ideally, if the old question hasn't been deleted *and* the users were the same, closing it as a dupe of that would be a good path to go.

However, if the user has created multiple questions analogous to this because their original one was put on hold, *or* they're different accounts altogether, then it is best to involve a diamond moderator.

A custom flag explaining what's going on would've been sufficient.

There's no need to name them here.  All *we're* going to do is pour fuel onto the fire.

Comment: Closing as a dupe isn't always possible though. If the original question never got any answers, the system won't allow it to be a dupe target.

Comment: "closing it as a dupe" is impossible, as they aren't the same users (ids).

Comment: Ah.  I hadn't realized that the two users weren't the exact same user.  I admit my mind was on autopilot there.  I'll revise that part of this answer.

Comment: There's also the problem that identifying instances of this are hard.  If a user asks a question, it gets closed/deleted, and they re-ask it 20 minutes later, sure, someone might remember the question, be able to find it, and handle the situation.  If they wait even a few hours, odds are fairly high nobody that saw the first question will notice the second, and even if they do, they may not be able to find the original.  And then even if you *do* figure it out and flag it, the user just posts *another* duplicate a few hours later, and repeat until they get their answer.

Comment: @Servy if someone's sure they've seen a very similar post before but can't recall a direct link - then raising a flag with as much info. as possible is fine. We'll most likely be able to track down old posts/user accounts from the post to see if it's a Q-ban / suspension evasion thing. (but yes - it does rely on someone noticing it...)

Comment: @JonClements - I only discovered this behavior because I was trying to edit the title and take out the trailing `]` assuming it was a fat finger typo and discovered that there was another question with the exact title and on inspection that that other question was the exact same content letter for letter but a different user. Then I saw the comments where they admitted to someone else what I just discovered.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an autoflagging system does a word intersection and count either words or phrases or sentences that are identical. Then a moderator comes along to decide on whether to accept it or not.

Then set the sensitivity to x% of words or sentences in common then it gets autoflagged. It may have to run as a cron job for completeness, or maybe limit the checking to the last months posts or something.

Comment: an approach like this would detect plagiarism in answers as well so it might be worth investing some time in it.

Comment: I had a thought that you could also use a sliding scale of probability for the sensitivity, common 'good' posters would have the sensitivity turned down automatically, new accounts would be higher.

Answer (score -12):

Leave a comment stating that the question is a repost, and then **flag the repost as "rude or abusive".** Reposting a question verbatim from a different account *just because* the original question is closed is blatant abuse of the site and should be dealt with accordingly.

Comment: By "flag as abusive", do you mean use the "rude or abusive" flag?  If so, then I disagree.  While it might be "abuse" of the site to do it, the rude or abusive flag is not intended to be used in such a manner.  A custom flag for a moderator is the appropriate course of action.  If that's not the flag you mean, the you should clarify that in your answer

Comment: agree with @psubsee2003 here - my _custom_ flag message for moderator would certainly include word "abuse" as it is abuse of the site indeed but i would not use [abusive kind of flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/165773)

Comment: No, a standard offensive flag is not what I'd recommend for this. That lacks the context we need to determine that this is a repost, and we're not going to know that this is one without some kind of explanation. Most likely, we'll try to look for offensive content within the post itself, not see it, and decline the flag. A custom flag is needed here, preferably with a link to the post this was copied from.